# I can't find jetty-https.xml in Nexus 3

Tags: docker, https, nexus, rancher, nexus3

I installed a instance of Nexus Repository Manager 3 in rancher and i'm trying to use https port for a docker hosted repository. This means that i need to create a self-signed certificate to make it work. After a lot of research i came down to a problem, i cant find jetty-https.xml in /etc. The questions is, do this file exist or do i need to create it?

Source:

- https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217542177?_ga=2.62350444.1144825414.1623920039-1845083682.1622816513
- https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-HowtoEnabletheHTTPSConnector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modify the nexus.properties file in /nexus-data/etc/ and uncomented the nexus-args and restart the container the jetty-https.xml appeared on $install-dir/etc/jetty/. if you check the logs you can see the exact location of the jetty config folder.